# how to use $localStorage dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I'm beginner in development Cordova AngularJS. I use `$localStorage` to persist data. I use like this:

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/evenements/' + $localStorage.idcategorie, {
    params: {
        fields: "titre_annonce,texte_annonce,adresse,imageJson",
        format: "json"
    }
}).then(function(result) {
    $localStorage.listEventParCategorie = result.data;
});
```

It's good, it works but now i want to check this condition

```
if ($localStorage.'listEventParCategorie' + idcategorie == null) {

}
```

*e.g.*: I concatenated `listEventParCategorie` with `idcategorie` to have `$localStorage` dynamic but is not worked. Please help me.

Comment: while assigning value you are not specifying `idcategorie` then how can you specify it for getting value?

Comment: use bracket notation: `$localStorage['listEventParCategorie'+idcategorie]`

Comment: better convert them to strings first and then concatenate compare .. bit time taking but clean

Answer (score 0):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) in your `if` condition:

```
if ($localStorage['listEventParCategorie' + idcategorie] == null) { ... }
```